# Forwarding post parameters in a redirect_to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, redirect, ruby-on-rails-5

In my rails app, I want the user to be able to select an option in a 'new' form, but if the option already exists, I want it to update the current option.

I have this so far in my create method:

```
def create

  @cost = Cost.new(cost_params)

  if Cost.exists?(:category => @cost.category, :option => @cost.option)
    redirect_to action: 'update', id: Cost.where(:category => @cost.category, :option => @cost.option).first.id
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cost.save
        format.html { redirect_to action: 'index', status: 303, notice: [true, 'Cost was successfully created.'] }
        format.json { render json: @cost, status: :created, location: @cost }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @cost.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that it redirects me to, for example `cost/9` url, which renders the show page. I want the id to send with the cost_params straight to the update method:

```
def update
  @cost = Cost.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @cost.update_attributes(cost_params)
      format.html { redirect_to action: 'index', status: 303, notice: [true, 'Cost was successfully updated.'] }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @cost.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Which should redirect to the index page.

is there any efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

And HTTP redirect always results in a GET request, not a POST request, so redirecting to `update` doesn't really make a lot of sense. That's not a Rails issue, that's just how HTTP works.

If you want to automatically update the relevant record, you have to do that from within the `create` action. The straightforward but lazy way would be to copy the code from update and paste it into `if` branch within `create`. The more correct way would be to extract the relevant part of `update` out into a separate, private method, and call that method from both `create` and `update`, something like:

```
def create
  @cost = Cost.new(cost_params)

  if Cost.exists?(:category => @cost.category, :option => @cost.option)
    @cost = Cost.where(:category => @cost.category, :option => @cost.option).first
    really_update
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cost.save
        format.html { redirect_to action: 'index', status: 303, notice: [true, 'Cost was successfully created.'] }
        format.json { render json: @cost, status: :created, location: @cost }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @cost.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end 

def update
  @cost = Cost.find(params[:id])
  really_update
end

private def really_update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @cost.update_attributes(cost_params)
      format.html { redirect_to action: 'index', status: 303, notice: [true, 'Cost was successfully updated.'] }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @cost.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```